# Joomla jdoc include not being recognised

Tags: php, joomla

I've placed below code at the top of the Joomla template but the position is not being recognised.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="topbanner" style="xhtml" />
```

Is there something I need to do to get this position showing up under modules?

Comment: Try it without "style" argument, otherwise check if the jdoc:include isn't in a PHP IF/ELSE statement that would never output the jdoc:include. Last i would try the jdoc at the end of the index.php (just for troobleshooting). Also don't forget to disable browser cache. PS: if none of these worked could you post your index.php code ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have create the above position in the templateDetails.xml

In case you have not create the position Please do it like this

```
<position>topbanner</position>
```

Comment: are you trying this in a module ...I think it will work only in template files

Comment: I'm putting this in template index.php file The position is also added to xml file

Comment: Then it should work, make sure there is no silly mistake...just like the position is created in some other tag ...you should create this postion under <positions> tag in the xml

Comment: What exactly was the issue here, as I've got the same thing... and have done every step here, but still the output doesn't seem to be generated.

Comment: @Lee I have the same issue I don't know how to fix it.